# What is this ground cover that looks like tiny cactus

Tags: identification, plant-recommendations, ground-cover

I found this in my front yard probably grew by previous owner. I am in Pacific Northwest.

[image]

What is this plant? Do they grow larger or stay small like that? How fast do they grow to cover more ground?

They look very nice.

Comment: We really do no see a lot of details. For me (as European) it could be Sedum, Saxifraga, Sempervivum. Usually they remain small, just the flower stem could be much higher. But I let stormy or other people near you to identify it. If you can take a close up, it could help.

Comment: What kind of light - full sun, part sun, or shade? It looks like it's growing in regular garden soil (or even forest duff). Is the soil well-drained?

Comment: This is in part sun. The soil is well drain garden soil